# put items into an array based on punctuation

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on a way to pull data from my mySQL database and display the text as an array however I have it so that only one string of data is available and each instance is separated by a comma example. 1,2,3,4 is there a way to have it break or start a new line after each comma instead of having a conglomerated mess that looks like this:

```
1 package KRAFT Deluxe Macaroni & Cheese Dinner Sharp Cheddar Cheese Sauce, 1 lb Ground Beef, 1 Jar Spaghetti Sauce, 1/2 Cup KRAFT Shredded Mozzarella Cheese
```

Code:

```
<?php

require_once '../scripts/app_config.php';
require_once '../../scripts/authorize.php';
require_once '../scripts/database_connection.php';

// Get the user ID of the user to show
$User_id = $_REQUEST['User_id'];

// Gets User Id
$select_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE User_id = " . $User_id;

// Run the query to get User Name
$result1 = mysql_query($select_query);
if ($result1) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
  $first_name     = $row['First_name'];
  $last_name      = $row['Last_name'];
  $email          = $row['Email'];
  $User_id          = $row['User_id'];

} else {
  handle_error("There was a problem finding your " .
               "information in our system.",
               "Error locating user with ID {$User_id}");

}

$Recipe_Id = $_REQUEST['Id'];

$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE Id = " . $Recipe_Id ) 
        or die(mysql_error());  

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $Id = $row['Id'];
      $Name =      $row['Name'];
    $Ingredients = $row['Ingredients'];
    $Category1 =   $row['Category1'];
    $Category2 =   $row['Category2'];
    $Directions =  $row['Directions'];
    $Creator =     $row['User_Name'];



?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Recipes</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="English">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/index.css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="header">  
    </div>

        <center>
        <span class="nav"><a href="recipes/index.php">Home</a></span>    <span class="nav"><a href="../recipes/addrecipe/index.php">New Recipe</a> </span>   <span class="nav"><a href="../scripts/signout.php">Sign Out</a> </span> 
        </center>


    <br>
    <div id="content">
<div class="user_profile">
            <h1><?php echo "{$first_name} {$last_name}";?></h1>

        </div>
      <div id="feature">
          <?php
echo "<H1>". $row['Name'] ."</H1>";
        echo "<p>" . $row['Category1'] . "</p>";
    echo "<p>" . $row['Category2'] . "</p>";
      echo "<p>" . $row['Creator'] . "</p>";

?>        </div>
<div class="column1">
    <h1>My Recipes</h1>
    <?php

    echo "<p>" . $row['Ingredients'] . "</p>";

 ?>           
      </div>

        <div class="column2">
            <h1>Directions</h1>
            <?php 
  echo "<p>" . $row['Directions'] . "</p>";
}
?>
        </div>

        <div class="column3">
            <h1>Recipes I Like</h1>


        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use comma-separated values in MySQL databases, normalize your data into a relation table.

Comment: Use `explode()` to split the value at commas, then use a `foreach` loop to print each ingredient on a different line.

Comment: are you talking about this line: `echo "<p>" . $row['Ingredients'] . "</p>";` ??

Comment: I was hoping to add the information into the database without the need for extra columns that may or may not be used or may or may not have enough to store information

Comment: **WARNING**: This is terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: based on the explode function it gives me `code Array ( [0] => 1 package KRAFT Deluxe Macaroni & Cheese Dinner Sharp Cheddar Cheese Sauce [1] => 1 lb Ground Beef [2] => 1 Jar Spaghetti Sauce [3] => 1/2 Cup KRAFT Shredded Mozzarella Cheese ) `

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes and it did not work unfortunately

Comment: what do you mean by `not work` ??? error messages? not breaking the line? try to replace not `', '` but just comma `','`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it correctly you just need something like this:

```
echo "<p>" . str_replace(', ',', <br />',$row['Ingredients']) . "</p>";
```